# Tailored WordPress Dashboard will remain after WP version update?

Tags: wordpress, customization, dashboard

### Hello guys

We're planning to custom **WordPress**' dashboard to make the admin look more e-commerce friendly. For instance:

```
   1. Enhance UI/UX Design.
   2. Add transitions and animations.
   3. Product-listing pictures bigger.
```

We aren't using plug-ins for this, therefore after tailoring, would it stay and won't break once we keep updating WordPress?

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do a comparison test by doing few modifications on your current version of WordPress vs the latest version. Also I would suggest doing this by building a plugin and not by changing the existing code as that will change on update.

Comment: Agree with @FahamShaikh, you should never edit WP core files as they may be erased in a future update. By creating a custom plugin, you will be able to make a better UI/UX for your users while keeping Core WP Dashboard for your Superadmin account and keeping the ability of updating WP without losing your customisations.

Comment: Thank you guys! We'll take that  to account, then it seems making a plug-in is the best practice.

:D